# Responsive layout, how to keep text at bottom of dynamically resizing image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to overlay some text on an image.
This is easy if the image location and size stays the same, but here I am allowing the image to dynamically resize based on screen size.

http://jsfiddle.net/xcs9L7u6/1/

When I set the position of the text to absolute, the text box is the right size, and I can place it at the bottom of the image just fine, but that doesn't work when the image bottom keeps changing due to window size.

So..

1. how do I keep the text at bottom of the resizing image height?
2. keep the text box to the width of the resizing width of the image?

HTML :

```
<div>
    <div class="gallery-background">
        <div class="gallery-text">Setting up some text to look at boats and fill space so that things move and wrap but need more text as it didn't quite give the right feel</div>
        <img src="http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/4530/396796-boat.jpg" class="galleryLrg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.gallery-background {
    margin: 1.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    /*needed for firefox and ie*/
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery-text {
    color: white;
    padding: .5rem;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .65);
    position: absolute;
}

.galleryLrg {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any thoughts would be great, 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you've go to do is to set `.gallery-background` to `position: relative`, and `gallery-text`to `position: absolute`. From there onwards, maintaining `.gallery-text` at the bottom of the image is just a matter of setting the `bottom`, `left` and `right` CSS attributes to `0`.

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xcs9L7u6/4/)**

**Code to be changed:**

```
.gallery-background {
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-text {
    position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set `.gallery-text` to `bottom: 0` and it will always sit at the bottom:

```
.gallery-text {
   color: white;
   padding: .5rem;
   max-width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .65);
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0; //add
}
```

and add `position:relative` to it's parent to keep it contained:

```
.gallery-background {
   margin: 1.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
   /*needed for firefox and ie*/
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden; //add to hide excess 
   position: relative; //add to contain absolute element 
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xcs9L7u6/3/)

Comment: Needed to re-arrange the divs so that a nested image would drive that divs size.  then the text sits within the same div, and with the bottom: 0 set, the text sits where it needs to as the image resizes..

I added the previous comments css, and then the following change to the html..

http://jsfiddle.net/xcs9L7u6/6/

.gallery {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

Comment: Thanks for the help.. just needed to look higher in the stack!!!
Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcs9L7u6/5/)

There two points you should modify,add these attributes.

```
.gallery-background {
    position:relative;
}
. gallery-text {    
    bottom:0;
}
```